# i have problem solving this problem, can anyone help me it's called the keys and rooms problem on leetcode

Tags: dynamic-programming, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

There are n rooms labeled from 0 to n - 1 and all the rooms are locked except for room 0. Your goal is to visit all the rooms. However, you cannot enter a locked room without having its key.

When you visit a room, you may find a set of distinct keys in it. Each key has a number on it, denoting which room it unlocks, and you can take all of them with you to unlock the other rooms.

Given an array rooms where rooms[i] is the set of keys that you can obtain if you visited room i, return true if you can visit all the rooms, or false otherwise.

Example 1:

Input: rooms = [[1],[2],[3],[]]
Output: true
Explanation:
We visit room 0 and pick up key 1.
We then visit room 1 and pick up key 2.
We then visit room 2 and pick up key 3.
We then visit room 3.
Since we were able to visit every room, we return true.
Example 2:

Input: rooms = [[1,3],[3,0,1],[2],[0]]
Output: false
Explanation: We can not enter room number 2 since the only key that unlocks it is in that room.

```
class Solution:
    def canVisitAllRooms(self, rooms: List[List[int]]) -> bool:
        hkey=[]
        count=0
        status=[False for i in range(len(rooms))]
        for i in rooms:
            for j in i:
                status[j]=True
        for i in range(len(status)):
            if status[i]==True:
                count+=1i
        if count==len(status)-1:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Initially, it passes the basic test cases but only few test cases are being handled by this....what else could be done inorder to make it perfect?

Comment: You're just counting how many keys exist, you need to determine if each of those keys is actually reachable. You could approach this by collecting keys, and using those to "unlock" other locations and add their keys to your collection. Start with the keys in room 0, and iterate over that list, adding the keys from each room to the end of your list, and removing the key and storing it in some "done" collection. Once you run out of keys to use, check which you have in the "done" pile (or just count them). If you've unlocked all the rooms, you're the winner

Answer (score 0):

Store an integer for the number of rooms total, an integer for number of rooms visited, iterate the entire thing and if your visited is smaller than total return false.

Comment: could you give me a code so that I can understand it more clearly?